# Is scriptblock parameter evaluation different for compiled cmdlets and advanced functions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In experimenting with scriptblocks, I was attempting to use a scriptblock parameter with an advanced function and noticed that it performs differently than when supplied to a compiled cmdlet.

In reviewing [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150713032512/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/powershell/archive/2006/06/23/643674.aspx) from the PowerShell Team blog, it appears that the PowerShell engine should be evaluating the scriptblock if a scriptblock is not a valid input for the parameter.  It seems that when calling the function with a scriptblock parameter, it attempts to convert a scriptblock to the parameters type directly, rather than evaluating the scriptblock based on the current object in the pipeline.

My intention is to duplicate behavior like:

```
Import-CSV somecsv.csv | get-wmiobject -class {$_.class} -Computer {$_.computer}
```

for advanced functions.

Example script:

```
$sb = {throw "If there was an error, the scriptblock was evaluated!"}

function test ()
{
  param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $ThisShouldBeEvaluatedForEachItem,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string]
    $FullName
 )  

 process 
 {  
  write-host $Fullname, $ThisShouldBeEvaluatedForEachItem
 }
} 
Get-ChildItem | test -ThisShouldBeEvaluatedForEachItem $sb
```

Is this the intended behavior or am I headed in the wrong direction?

Based on [Keith's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301283/is-scriptblock-parameter-evaluation-different-for-compiled-cmdlets-and-advanced-f/3301833#3301833), I added ValueFromPipeline and ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName (in two separate tests) to the Parameter attribute for the ThisShouldBeEvaluatedForEachItem  parameter.  Doing that makes the example work, though it seems to defeat the stated purpose of scriptblock parameters from the Team Blog post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the parameter is `ValueFromPipeline` or `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` then PowerShell will evaluate the Scriptblock and try to coerce the result to the parameter type. We got this info from the PowerShell team a while back:

> ScriptBlock arguments are passed as is
>   (as a ScriptBlock) when the parameter
>   type is Object, ScriptBlock, or a type
>   deriving from ScriptBlock, or
>   collections of these types.
>
> We only invoke the ScriptBlock
>   argument during parameter binding when
>   there is pipeline input and there was
>   no trivial way to bind the ScriptBlock
>   directly.

Comment: Actually, it does seem to work properly with   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName as well, as long as the parameter that has the scriptblock is noted to come from the pipeline.  See my updated question. 

Thanks Keith.

Comment: Sorry, I added that to the example above.. I forgot that in my earlier cut/paste.  The above was my initial trial.  I'll clarify the intention above.

Comment: Doh. Yes it works. That's what I call a "self-induced mock" on my part. :-)